# Validar evento Onclick en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quiero realizar una validación en un botón para limpiar mis forms al dar click en botón salir :

```
if (document.getElementById('btnsalirmodalf').onclick == true) {
    document.getElementById('asignadoa').value == '';
    document.getElementById('Estatus').value == '';
    document.getElementById('porcentaje').value == '';
    document.getElementById('exampleFormControlTextarea1').value == '';
    document.getElementById('exampleFormControlTextarea2').value == '';
}
```

El problema es que no se si en está parte:

```
document.getElementById('btnsalirmodalf').onclick == true
```

estoy haciendolo bien ya que no me realiza ningún cambio al dar click en salir. Tienen una sugerencia por favor?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que definir una función al hacer click en el botón.

```
document.getElementById('btnsalirmodalf').onclick = () => {
  // Código a ejecutar al hacer click
}
```

Dentro de la función del click tienes que definir los elementos a los cuales les vas a cambiar el valor. Para eso te funciona tu `document.getElementById`. Pero en tu ejemplo estás utilizando `==` en lugar de `=`.

```
document.getElementById('btnsalirmodalf').onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById('asignadoa').value = '';
  document.getElementById('Estatus').value = '';
  document.getElementById('porcentaje').value = '';
  document.getElementById('exampleFormControlTextarea1').value = '';
  document.getElementById('exampleFormControlTextarea2').value = '';
}
```

Comment: Nunca había probado con eso document.getElementById('btnsalirmodalf').onclick = () =>  {}, funciona muy bien , gracias . Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Crea una función que haga lo que necesitas y al momento de encerar (poner en blanco el input), asigna el valor de "" solamente con un "=" no con dos.

Intenta con este código:

```js
function limpia() {
  document.getElementById("asignadoa").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Estatus").value = "";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnsalirmodalf" onclick="limpia()">Limpiar</button>
<input type="text" id="asignadoa"/>
<input type="text" id="Estatus" />
...
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono perfectamente.  Saludos!!!.